# How to have the sum for the numbers in a string line?

Tags: java, character, charat

Here I in this task I need to use the generated string data to loop over all characters on it then sum only the numbers within the string.
example: If we have this data string

```
 5f395d07369071a505ef926527de2ac53e8c29e103dc63398315bc276224b81a
```

Then the result will be when taking only the numbers and adding them together is 2407

this is the code :

```java
String studentId="22011151";
String studentName="Abed Alrahman Abuhilal";

int total=0;
String data =generateData(studentId);  //here is a method I didn't show
```

I have a logic error here

```java
for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    Boolean ok = Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i));
    total+=data.charAt(i);

System.out.println("StudentId:"+studentId+" my name is:"+studentName+" total is:"+total);
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Getting 2407 is wrong or do you need to get 2407 as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

`String.charAt` returns (in this case) an ASCII representation of a character ('0' = 0x30, '1' = 0x31 etc). To get a digit you should change your line in loop with the the following:

`total += data.charAt(i) - '0';`

---

UPD: By applying this change and Geoff Zoref's suggestion you should get the working code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what logic error you are having, but I have a few suggestions. The Boolean `ok` is, as far as I can tell, unused. Even if you did use it, you would need to couch the line `total+=data.charAt(i);` in an `if` statement so that only the digits get added to total. Something like this:

```
      String data ="5f395d07369071a505ef926527de2ac53e8c29e103dc63398315bc276224b81a";
      int total = 0;
        
        for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i)))
                total += data.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.charAt(i)` returns ASCII value related to the character.

Hence you get the wrong answer.

So without applying the char value directly, follow the following steps.

1. Get the string value of char
2. Parse the string value to int

   ```
   for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++) {
           Boolean ok = Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i));
           if (ok)
               total += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(data.charAt(i)));
   ```

   }

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you are adding the char value to your total. This is **not** the same as adding the value of the digit. For example the ASCII value for 0 is 48, as you can see in the table in this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) entry. One solution to your problem is to write your sum like this:

```java
total += Data.charAt(i) - '0';
```

You can do this because you already know that the character is a digit and all digits in ASCII are in order by their value (0 is 48, 1 is 49, etc.).